# How to call a VBS script from C# managed code

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript

You would think this would be simple...
From the command line I can execute

```
c:\windows\system32\cscript c:\windows\system32\iisext.vbs /ListFile
```

But when I try it from managed code...

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cscript";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"c:\windows\system32\iisext.vbs /ListFile";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
using (StreamReader sr = proc.StandardOutput) {
...
```

I get this error:

> *Input Error: Can not find script file
>   "c:\windows\system32\iisext.vbs"*

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You're sure that file exists and you have access to it?

Comment: Can you just do one arg: "c:\windows\system32\iisext.vbs" (without the extra arg after it)?

Comment: Can you please try to run your program on "Admin mode".?

Comment: Surely it is because your program runs in 32-bit mode.  Change the platform target setting to AnyCPU or use c:\windows\sysnative

Comment: TheGreatCO - Yes, tgolisch - Tried that, Awesome - Tried that

Comment: Hans - That was indeed the issue.  Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hans is correct; the problem is almost certainly that you're running in 32bit mode, which means that C:\windows\system32 doesn't point where you think. (Verify by watching file access with Process Monitor).

Use C:\windows\sysnative instead, or compile your app to target AnyCPU.

Comment: Is `C:\windows\sysnative` automatically redirecting to the right place?